# ReactJS + VideoJS. Prevent VideoJS from rerendering (e.g. starting over)

Tags: reactjs, state, video.js

I want to build a video player with loop functionality. Every loop will have a start and end timestamp. These loops will be persisted to the database.

The problem is that even when nothing at all changes about the video data, it will rerender when it revalidates. I presume this happens because the video is "playing" and thus it's html no longer matches on revalidate (E.g. the time in the HTML element has moved to 00:00:04).

I tried to wrap it in `memo()` but it keeps rerendering anyway.

In short; the player needs access to the "loops" data, but it can't rerender onchange of said data because the video will start at 00:00:00.

I'm not sure whether code is applicable here, but:

```
import { useLoaderData, useRevalidator } from "react-router-dom";
import Container from "../../generic/Container";
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';
import client from '../../../apolloClient';
import { useRef } from "react";
import VideoJS from "../../generic/VideoJS";
import Video from "../../../types/models/Video";

export const VideoPlayer = () => {
    const data = useLoaderData() as Video;
    const revalidator = useRevalidator();
    const playerRef = useRef(null) as any;

    const handlePlayerReady = (player: any) => {
        playerRef.current = player;
    };
    
    return (
        <>
            <VideoJS
                options={{
                    autoplay: true,
                    controls: true,
                    responsive: true,
                    sources: [{
                        src: data.video_url,
                        type: 'video/mp4'
                    }]
                }}
            />
            <div className="py-14">
                <Container>
                    <button onClick={() => {revalidator.revalidate()}} type="button" className="text-white">Refresh!</button>
                </Container>
            </div>
        </>
            
    );
}
```